# How do I print my inserted values in my console? (Flutter | sqflite)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, cross-platform, mobile-application, sqflite

I am currently successfully able to insert values into the system, however, I want to be able to display the inserted values in my console.
How do I print the inserted values in my console? I tried doing so and I was only able to get the "id" of the inserted value. I'm not sure how to print the rest of the values in the table.

Here's my insert code:

```
  // Insert Operation: Insert a Note object to database
  Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
    //getting db reference
    Database db = await database;
    //running the insert command
    //our data from note is converted to map object
    var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Note data inserted successfully: $result');
    } 
    return result;
  }
```

Here's the code I used to convert the Note object into a Map object

```
  // Convert a Note object into a Map object
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String,dynamic>{};
    if (id != null) {
      map['id'] = _id;
    }
    map['title'] = _title;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['priority'] = _priority;
    map['color'] = _color;
    map['date'] = _date;

    return map;
  }
```

This is the result on my console:

[image: console print result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert row in database you will only get row id in return.

So if you want to print recent data then you have to make a query to your database with id or you can also print all the data available.

For table

```
db.query("table_name);
```

or

```
db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM "table"');
```

For specific id

```
db.query("table_name",where: '$rowId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
```

or

```
db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE $rowId = $id');
```

For more info check : https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite